# How do i prove this this group is isomorphic to this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do I prove that $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} / \langle(1,2)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}\times \Bbb Z_2$?

I was trying to find a corresponding homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times \Bbb Z_2$ such that $\ker(\phi)=\langle(1,2)\rangle$, but I cannot think of one.

How do I prove this?

Comment: $\Bbb Z\times Z_2$ has an element of order $2$, but $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/\langle(1,2)\rangle$ does not. Are you sure you've given us the original problem in its original form? This isn't a true/false question you've sneakily made us answer, is it?

Comment: I think the result of quatient is just $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @messel How do i show that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define

$$\;\phi: \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z\;,\;\;\phi(m,n)=2m-n$$

Show that $\;\phi\;$ is an epimorphism of groups and also that

$$(m,n)\in\ker \phi\iff (m,n)\in\langle\;(1,2)\;\rangle$$

Thus, the claim in the OP is false...or I am wrong, of course.

Comment: I think you mean $\phi$ is a *surjective homomorphism* of groups.

Comment: Of course, @AymanHourieh. Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ are spanned by $\langle 1,2 \rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle$  with integer coefficients.

So result of quotient is $\langle 0,1 \rangle \cong \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Using group presentations, let $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \cong \langle x, y \rangle_{ab}$. Then
$$
\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / \langle (1, 2)\rangle \cong \langle x, y \mid x + 2y\rangle_{ab} \cong \langle y \rangle \cong \Bbb Z.
$$

We were able to remove $x$ from the presentation since $x = -2y$.